# Re-Render React Component After AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm building a CRUD application with React and I wondered if you could help on this issue.

I am making a AJAX GET request with`componentDidMount` to the server which retrieves the data and then sets the state in the success function. In the render function I then map over the `state` array and render each state into a `<li>` element and include a `<button>` element.

When the `<button>` element is clicked it calls the `delete()` function. This then calls the AJAX DELETE request on the ID.

My problem is how do I get the component to re-render or update the state after the AJAX request is a success?

```
import React from 'react';

class PostList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/posts',
       type: "GET",
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
         this.setState({posts: data})
       }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  delete(event) {
    let postId = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-id");
      $.ajax({
         url: '/posts/' + postId,
         type: "DELETE",
         success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
         }.bind(this)
      });
  }

  render() {
    let posts = this.state.posts.map( (index) => {
      return <li data-id={index._id} className="list-group-item"><a href={"posts/" + index._id}>{index.title}</a><button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.delete.bind(this)}>Delete</button></li>
    })
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {posts}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default PostList;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update the state in the `delete` handler.

You've got two options:

1. optimistic, it instantly updates the UI, however, the request could fail and you need to handle this case.

   ```
   delete(event) {
     let postId = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-id");
     this.setState({
       posts: this.state.posts.filter(post => post._id !== postId)
     })
     $.ajax({
        url: '/posts/' + postId,
        type: "DELETE"
     });
   }
   ```
2. pessimistic, will only mutate the state with a successful request, but could take a while before the UI is updated.

   ```
   delete(postId) {
     $.ajax({
        url: '/posts/' + postId,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function(data) {
         this.setState({
           posts: this.state.posts.filter(post => post._id !== postId)
         })
        }.bind(this)
     });
   }
   ```

---

For handling state, you could dive into state management libraries like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux).

Answer (score 1):

You can force update using the component's `forceUpdate()` method. That will ensure you re-render. However, it'd be better if you responded to whatever that call returned by setting the state, which will also re-render.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how the rest of your app works, but I guess your code is a module of something "bigger". Since you use es2015 syntax I think you can achive what you want like this.

What you want is to update the state on your `<MyApp />` or what ever you have. And then you pass the state as a prop and the function that will update the state of your `<MyApp />` like this `<PostList posts={this.state.posts} onDelete={this.onDelete()}/>`

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    posts: []
  }
}

onDelete(data){
  this.setState({posts: data})
}

render(){
  return (    
    <div>
      <PostList posts={this.state.posts} onDelete={this.onDelete()}/> 
    </div>
  )}
}
```

Here you change your onClick to `(e)=> this.delete(e)` (if you use fat arrow functions you do not need to bind this anymore.

In your delete function you can now call `onDelete(data)`that is in your `<MyApp />` with the data. This will make your app re-render everyhitng.

```
import React from 'react';

        class PostList extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/posts',
       type: "GET",
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
         this.setState({posts: data})
       }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  delete(event) {
    let postId = event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-id");
    let data;
      $.ajax({
         url: '/posts/' + postId,
         type: "DELETE",
         success: function(_d) {
          data = _d;
         }.bind(this)
      });
      onDelete(data);
  }

  render() {
    let posts = this.props.posts.map( (index) => {
      return <li data-id={index._id} className="list-group-item"><a href={"posts/" + index._id}>{index.title}</a><button className="btn btn-default" onClick={(e)=> this.delete(e)}>Delete</button></li>
    })
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {posts}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default PostList;
```

Good luck!